# Why "npm update" will update the module(s) but not its SemVer in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, module, package.json

1. In "package.json," I clearly have an outdated express module version --> "4.10.0"

[image]

2. "npm outdated" is recommending an update to "4.17.1"

[image]

3. although "npm update" updated the express module to "4.17.1", "package.json" remains "4.10.0"

[image]

My question is: how do I update both the module(s) and "package.json" simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates).

At first I didn't want to install something for this basic task but `npm` lacks this "basic" option

Comment: Thanks Raphael for the prompt and brilliant reply. I can't believe "npm-check-updates" is not built into npm but it sure does solve the updating issue :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a package to update you can install a specific version with npm (instead of update)

```
npm install --save-exact express@4.16.1
```

Yarn also supports this for `add`/`upgrade` without the extra option.

```
yarn upgrade express@4.16.1
```

It's unwieldy for large updates though, see [Raphael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68915022/1318694)